# Simple getter logic in ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Is it ok to have simple logic (without any dependencies) in ViewModels getters or it should contain just automatic properties? in this case just checking for null so I don't have to do that in controller each time I am using this ViewModel. TicketSearchParameters is a simple model containing string and date properties, there is no Repository or any other dependencies.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private TicketSearchParameters _searchParams;
    public TicketSearchParameters SearchParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (_searchParams == null)
            {
                _searchParams = new TicketSearchParameters();
                _searchParams.CreatedFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
                _searchParams.CreatedTo = DateTime.Now;
            }
            return _searchParams;
        }
        set
        {
            _searchParams = value;
        }
    }

    /*** other properties ***/

}
```

Comment: If your wanting to set defaults, that is what a constructor is for - `public MyViewModel(){ SearchParams = new TicketSearchParameters(){ CreatedFrom  =  DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7), CreatedTo = DateTime.Now }; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke So then the question would be, is it ok to have this kind of logic in a ViewModel constructor?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I'm asking cause some say that models should not have any logic at all, and all logic should be handled in controller. You could write an answer related to all this and I'll accept it.

Comment: There is no right or wrong way here. All three will work, but a purpose of a default constructor is initialize default values in your model (and the compiler creates one anyway if you don't have any others). And it means keeping it DRY (not repeating that code in a controller every time you want to initialize your model assuming you always want those defaults)

Answer (score 0):

You code is fairly ok. But you can use **NULL Object Design Pattern** to check null and create NullObject.

make a class named NullSearchParams inherited from SearchParams and initialize it when needed.

You can see Null design pattern documentation here.

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object